# Can't use method of object in other method. Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I am trying to make a timer. Therefor I made an object `Timer`. I get stuck when I am trying to start the timer (`startTimer`). I want to use setInterval to count down and want to use `runTimer` as the callback.

I thought I could use `self.runTimer` to do this. Unfortunately this does not work (`uncaught TypeError: self.runTimer is not a function`).

How should I do this?

This is the greater part of my code.

```
var mins;
var secs;
var isPaused;
var countdownID;
var bigTime = 1499;

var Timer = {
  runTimer: function () {
      mins = Math.floor(bigTime / 60);
      secs = bigTime - mins * 60;

      // change the HTML to show new minutes and seconds
      minutes.innerHTML = (mins < 10 ? '0' : '') + mins;
      seconds.innerHTML = (secs < 10 ? '0' : '') + secs;

      if (bigTime == 0) {
          bigTime = 1499;
          clearInterval(countdownID);
      } else if (!isPaused) {
          bigTime = bigTime - 1;
      }
  },

  startTimer: function () {
        message.innerHTML = "timer started";
        countdownID = setInterval("self.runTimer()", 1000);
  },

  resetTimer: function () {
      message.innerHTML = "Let's focus!";

      bigTime = 1499;
      minutes.innerHTML = "25";
      seconds.innerHTML = "00";

      isPaused = false;
  },

  resumeTimer: function () {
    message.innerHTML = "timer resumed";
    isPaused = false;
  },

  stopTimer: function () {
    message.innerHTML = "timer stopped";
    isPaused = true;
  }
};
```

I have 4 buttons (start, stop, resume, reset) that are listening for clicks to start/stop/resume/reset the timer.

Comment: Why would it work? You never define `self` anywhere.

Comment: @Quentin Isn't self the Timer object?

Comment: Why would it be? Are you thinking of `this`?

Comment: I think you intent to use `this`.

Comment: You should have code like this `countdownID = setInterval(Timer.runTimer, 1000);` It will work because You never use `this` so You do not have to bind it anywhere.

Comment: Oh, I was indeed thinking of this. But the existing question answers my question pretty good.